# Bootstrap 5 card tile position adding conflict

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm tiring to using [bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/) card to my attached image like card view, does any one know how to do that correctly on bootstrap 5 ?

here the my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>My </title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body >

<!--Start main layout-->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="">
            <div class="container">
            <div id="dynamic content" class="dynamic-content">
                <div class="row align-items-center animated flipInY slow delay-2s">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="content" id="tile1">
                            <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>My Book</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="content" id="tile2">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>About</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="content" id="tile3">
                            <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>Services</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="content" id="tile4">
                            <i class="fa fa-comment fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>Feedback</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="content" id="tile5">
                            <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>Portfolio</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="content" id="tile6">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>Contact</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="content" id="tile7">
                            <i class="fa fa-quote-right fa-5x"></i>
                            <p>Free Quote</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!--End of main layout-->
</body>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</html>
```

Thanks[image]

Comment: you can use grid and check out this link

https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/YGQKAy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use Bootstrap 5 grid system

Use class `.row` to make rows and class `.col` to make columns.

As stated on Bootstrap 5 [official website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/): *There are 12 template columns available per row, allowing you to create different combinations of elements that span any number of columns. Column classes indicate the number of template columns to span (e.g. col-4 spans four).*

This is why I used `.col-3` four times. These four `.col-3` make four main "sections". All together they make up to maximal 12 columns per row (i.e. 3 * 4 = 12). Inside these four main "sections" there are bunch of `.row`s and `.col`s.

#### Which .col should you use?

Use `.col-5` and `.col-11` like this:

- `.col-5` two times inside the same `.row` if you want to have
  **two boxes** in a row or
- `.col-11` one time inside the same `.row` if you want to have **one box** in a row.

#### Why these two (i.e., .col-5 and .col-11)?

Why not `.col-6` and `.col-12`? Well, if you use `.col-6` two times inside the same `.row`, there will not be any space left in between these boxes. Remember, there are maximal 12 columns per row! If you use `.col-6` two times, you fill up the whole row (6 * 2 = 12). But if you use `.col-5` two times, there is still some space left (5 * 2 = 10).

**Using `.col-5` two times inside the same `.row`:**

[image: Using .col-5 two times inside the same .row]

**Using `.col-6` two times inside the same `.row`:**

[image: Using .col-6 two times inside the same .row]

By default, if you use `.col-5` two times in the same `.row` (see the first image), these two columns will position themselves so that there will be some space in between them.

Use `.col-11` purely from aesthetical standpoint. If you use `.col-11` below or above a row with two `.col-5` these two rows will be the same width (if you use `.col-12` this row will be wider than the row below or above with two `.col-5`). But in order to achieve both rows to be the same width, you also need to add `.d-flex .justify-content-around` to all rows where you want to have two boxes in a row to "push these two boxes apart from each other" and therefore make this row the same width as the one below or above. For more information, see [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content).

#### Other stuff

Use class `.d-flex .justify-content-center` for the horizontal alignment and class `.d-flex .align-items-center` for the vertical alignment. With these two you can center your content (i.e. Font Awesome icons and titles) inside all of these boxes horizontally and vertically at the same time.

Be careful, you also need to wrap your Font Awesome icon and the title with `<div class='text-center'>...</div>` like this if you want to center the text (not the boxes but the text):

```
<div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center one'>
    <div class='text-center'>
        <i class='fa fa-home fa-5x'></i>
        <div id='white'>My book</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end of the HTML add an image. Add CSS like this:

- `position: absolute;` and `z-index: -100;` to put it in the background (without `position: absolute;` the z-index will not work and consequently the image will not be put in the background),
- `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;` to make the image full screen width and height and
- `filter: blur(50px);` to add the blur effect.

#### The snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#inner_wrapper {
  margin-top: -15vh;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  /* Set this value the same as the margin-top for the #inner_wrapper. */
}

.col-5,
.col-11 {
  border-radius: 1vw;
}

.fa-home {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  color: white;
}

#white {
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: white;
}

.one {
  background-color: #2c78e2;
}

.two {
  background-color: #15bb88;
}

.three {
  background-color: #e27b2c;
}

.four {
  background-color: #1a65ac;
}

.five {
  background-color: #15bb88;
}

.six {
  background-color: #8cc63e;
}

.seven {
  background-color: #e27b2c;
}

.eight {
  background-color: #e27b2c;
}

.nine {
  background-color: #b44be8;
}

.ten {
  background-color: #2c78e2;
}

.eleven {
  background-color: #2c78e2;
}

.twelve {
  background-color: #8cc63e;
}

#img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -100;
  filter: blur(50px);
  -moz-filter: blur(50px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  -o-filter: blur(50px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/js/all.js' data-auto-replace-svg='nest'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='wrapper' class='d-flex align-items-center'>
    <div id='inner_wrapper' class='row'>
      <div class='col-3'>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-around'>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center one'>
            <div class='text-center'>
              <i class='fa fa-home fa-5x'></i>
              <div id='white'>My book</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center two'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-around'>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center three'></div>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center four'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-3'>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-center'>
          <div class='col-11 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center five'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-around'>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center six'></div>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center seven'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-3'>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-around'>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center eight'></div>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center nine'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-center'>
          <div class='col-11 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ten'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-3'>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-start'>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center eleven'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row m-2 d-flex justify-content-start'>
          <div class='col-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center twelve'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <img id='img' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg'>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bootstrap Card Solution

<sup>with minimal css</sup>

### The Layout

```css
#groups {
  min-width: 1140px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/W3BxqV7.png);
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group.col {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Sheffield haworth </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="groups">
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### With Styling

Automated using JavaScript, but easy to implement with CSS nonetheless

```js
const colors = ["#2C78E2", "#43BB88", "#E27B2D", "#1A65AC", "#43BB88", "#8CC53E", "#E27B2D", "#E27B2D", "#B44BE8", "#2C78E2", "#2C78E2", "#8CC53E"];;
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(function(e, i) {
  e.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
})
```

```css
#groups {
  min-width: 1140px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/W3BxqV7.png);
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group.col {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Sheffield haworth </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="groups">
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### With Content

```js
const colors = ["#2C78E2", "#43BB88", "#E27B2D", "#1A65AC", "#43BB88", "#8CC53E", "#E27B2D", "#E27B2D", "#B44BE8", "#2C78E2", "#2C78E2", "#8CC53E"];;
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(function(e, i) {
  e.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
})
```

```css
#groups {
  min-width: 1140px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/W3BxqV7.png);
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group.col {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Sheffield haworth </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="groups">
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Large</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Large</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col">
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### Responsive

```js
const colors = ["#2C78E2", "#43BB88", "#E27B2D", "#1A65AC", "#43BB88", "#8CC53E", "#E27B2D", "#E27B2D", "#B44BE8", "#2C78E2", "#2C78E2", "#8CC53E"];;
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(function(e, i) {
  e.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/W3BxqV7.png);
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group.col {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Sheffield haworth </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="groups">
      <div class="group col-md">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col-md">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Large</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col-md">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Large</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group col-md">
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="width:138px">
          <div class="card col item">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Small</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello there, that's a great , but mobile responsive not working